# navigator.notification.activityStart() not working in blackberry OS 7 but working in android

Tags: javascript, android, html, blackberry, cordova

I am using phonegap 1.1.0 and using activityStart() on submit of a button to authenticate the data with server, this works fine in android but is not working in blackberry OS 7 device. How can i get it to work on all the devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, navigator.notification.activityStart() is not currently supported on BB.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, so will i have to use a gif image or something similar?

Comment: Yeah, you'd have to do something in HTML for now.